# set fill color marker google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I use my last column to set the color of the marker?

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name', 'Color'],
      [0.001, 0.002, 'Test 1', '#56df23'],
      [0.003, 0.004, 'Test 2', '#0023f6']
    ]);
    
    
    var options = {
        
        showTip: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true
        
        
    };

    var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
    
    
    
    map.draw(data, options);
  }
```

While googling and stackoverflowing, I found this related topic: [Google Maps: set custom color for type of markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081778/google-maps-set-custom-color-for-type-of-markers)

But the solution I am looking for must have these properties:

- colors are defined by users (= no use png images)
- I want to use the default marker, not a circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Symbols](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)

```
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1
    };
}
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3db77ff/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var data = [
  /* ['Lat', 'Long', 'Name', 'Color'], */
  [47.5, -122.0, 'Test 1', '#56df23'],
  [47.6, -122.2, 'Test 2', '#0023f6'],
  [47.7, -122.1, 'Test 2', 'yellow']
];

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.605, -122.333);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: pinSymbol('red')
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0], data[i][1]),
      icon: pinSymbol(data[i][3])
    });
  }
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor: '#000',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    scale: 1
  };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the color of the marker, you can only change the icon associated to a marker

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  map: map,
  icon:'youricon.png'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the standard marker pin color.

You have to build your own usin Icon or Symbol.

If you don't wan't to use PNG you can use SVG, with SVG you can change the way your icon looks like without a backend server.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: 'data:image/svg+xml,<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 438.536 438.536" style="enable-background:new 0 0 438.536 438.536;" xml:space="preserve"><g><path fill="gree" d="M322.621,42.825C294.073,14.272,259.619,0,219.268,0c-40.353,0-74.803,14.275-103.353,42.825c-28.549,28.549-42.825,63-42.825,103.353c0,20.749,3.14,37.782,9.419,51.106l104.21,220.986c2.856,6.276,7.283,11.225,13.278,14.838c5.996,3.617,12.419,5.428,19.273,5.428c6.852,0,13.278-1.811,19.273-5.428c5.996-3.613,10.513-8.562,13.559-14.838l103.918-220.986c6.282-13.324,9.424-30.358,9.424-51.106C365.449,105.825,351.176,71.378,322.621,42.825zM270.942,197.855c-14.273,14.272-31.497,21.411-51.674,21.411s-37.401-7.139-51.678-21.411c-14.275-14.277-21.414-31.501-21.414-51.678c0-20.175,7.139-37.402,21.414-51.675c14.277-14.275,31.504-21.414,51.678-21.414c20.177,0,37.401,7.139,51.674,21.414c14.274,14.272,21.413,31.5,21.413,51.675C292.355,166.352,285.217,183.575,270.942,197.855z"/></g></svg>',
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k510L9u2/

With SVG you can use more advanced graphics then using the Symbol option, with Symbols you can create SVG paths only.